# Continue saving node under some condition

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a drupal function can i use to check some condition, if it return true the node will be saved if not it should be return to the creation form.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from your comment above:

> i have a float field i want to compare it with another node field

Would the [Field Validation](http://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module help?

> This module adds an extra tab to each field instance, allowing you to
>   specify validation rules for your field instances.

Comment: i selected PHP Validation, but i don't have any values in column field (textbox) and it's required. what to do?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [hook_node_validate()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_validate/7) to check your condition.

> Perform node validation before a node is created or updated.
>
> This hook is invoked from node_validate(), after a user has has
>   finished editing the node and is previewing or submitting it. It is
>   invoked at the end of all the standard validation steps, and after the
>   type-specific hook_validate() is invoked.
>
> To indicate a validation error, use form_set_error().

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i can't use it because i don't use a custom module, i'm using Computed field, is there another solution.thanks again

Comment: Ok What are you trying to validate ?

Comment: i have a float field i want to compare it with another node field, if it's less that the another field i will to complete the saving if not stop it.

Comment: Is the float field a Computed field or a regular CCK field ?

Comment: it's a CCK field